# Fetching the value from Registry

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I want to check the value for the following keys:-

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range1] 
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range2]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range3]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range4]
```

It is required because when I run a .reg file named 'securityNT.reg' which is required as a pre-requisite in my project, it updates the value for these keys. 
I am aware that these key contains the value for trusted sites.

I am using following code to fetch these values:

```
bool flagIESettings = false;
    string strKeyIESettings = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges";
    string valRange1 = "", valRange2 = "", valRange3 = "", valRange4 = "";
    using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey keyIESettings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(strKeyIESettings))
      {
        foreach (string subkey_name in keyIESettings.GetSubKeyNames())
          {
            using (RegistryKey subkey = keyIESettings.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
             {
               switch (subkey_name)
                 {
                  case "Range1" :
                     if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                      {
                         valRange1 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                      }                                
                       break;

                        case "Range2" :
                            if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                            {
                                valRange2 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                            }                                
                            break;

                        case "Range3":
                            if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                            {
                                valRange3 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Range4":
                            if (subkey.GetValue(":Range") != null)
                            {
                                valRange4 = subkey.GetValue(":Range").ToString();
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (valRange1 == "10.237.24.165" && valRange2 == "10.237.24.166" && valRange3 == "10.237.24.167" && valRange4 == "10.237.24.168")
        {
            flagIESettings = true;
        }
```

I am using Registry.CurrentUser to fetch the values for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` but this object(keyIESettings) is fetching values from `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20`. 
This is the main problem that I want to fetch values from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` but value is fetched from HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20.

I have made an observation that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1014` on my machine are in sync, may be because it is the current user. 
If object fetches values from `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1014` then my purpose will be done. Please let me know how i can fetch values from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1014`

Comment: I'm guessing you are running this code in a service.  So it uses the service's account.  Don't use a service.

Comment: This code is not of a service...I am calling this code from a .cs file which is a part of my web appication

Comment: A "web application" runs on a web server.  In a service.  Changing the Internet zone security settings of the web server makes no sense.  You cannot otherwise change the security settings of the user that runs the browser to visit your server.  They'd throw you in jail for something like that.

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant but I cant help it and this is the requirment of the project and I cannot change it :(

Answer (score 1):

You've said yourself that you *can* get values from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, you're just not getting the values you expect/want.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is a virtual link in the registry to the key of the user that is currently logged in (hence the name).  As you've noted, when you're logged in this is "synced" to `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-507921405-1993962763-682003330-1014`.

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20` is the "Network service" user (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330) for a list of well known IDs).  I would guess from this that you are running your program as a service (either a website under IIS or a Windows Service).

This being the case, you won't (or at least shouldn't) have access to a local user's registry hive.  You need to be running your application as the user you intend to edit (or possibly as a local) in order to access this.